In MVGAM, how can I model an interaction between 1 continuous variable (Abundance), 1 discrete (time in days) and 1 factor (the Genus of eukaryotes)
I'm working in microbial ecology and I'm trying to modelize the influence of the abundance of several genuses on a single genus of interest through time in a situation of primary succession of microorganisms. I've created this model, but I'm really unsure if I understand everything correctly, especially in regard to the interaction.
I've found several topics discussing 1 variable and factors, but not 1 continuous variable (Abundance), one discrete (time) and factors (Genuses)

Alkanindiges is the column containing the relative abundance of my genus of interest
Abundance is the relative abundance all the Genuses for each day
time is the days (1-24)
bioreactor is my experimental triplicate (there are 3 of them)

I use CAR(1) as I expect the abundance of my genus of interest for the previous day to have an influence on the abundance on the current day, but I'm missing some data points.
Here is the full model and I included the summary of the data I'm working with. If you want the whole file, I'd be glad to send it to you via e-mail!
Thank you very much for your time.

mod_alk <- mvgam( Alkanindiges ~ te(Abundance, time, by = Genus) + s(bioreactor, bs = 're'),

       trend_model = CAR(1),

       noncentred = TRUE,

       data = AHAPCN_train, 

       chains = 4,

       adapt_delta = 0.97,

       max_treedepth = 14,
 
       parallel = TRUE,

       backend = 'cmdstanr',

       family = Gamma(link = 'inverse')) 

and here is the summary of my df. The NAs are because I separated the abundance column into many columns for the abundance of each genus.


This model will be difficult to identify as it will let the effect of Abundance for each level of Genus vary through time, but you only have 17 total timepoints to learn these relationships. It will also include a main effect of time, which may compete with the autoregressive residuals and be tough to identify. I would consider a Beta observation family (family = betar()) to be more appropriate for proportional data. For more guidance, you may want to consider posting this on the {mvgam} Discussion Board.
